# Reseller API from Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-reseller-api

I'm trying to use the Reseller API for reporting on subscriptions via a Google Spreadsheet.
Please can someone get me started on the right track for authentication?

I've hacked my script to work using a "manually" generated "Authorization":"Bearer ..." header, but I can't expect my colleagues to do the same!